# New Site Redirected to old while under

Tags: redirect, development, websites, redirect-url, ce-1.9.2.3

Glad I was directed to this site. any help would be much appreciated!

I am developing my first Magento site.
I have a VPS server.
I copied my current website over to a /TEMP folder.
I have created a subdomain for the /TEMP folder store.mydomain.com

Magento is going to be installed on my main domain and /public_html folder

I would like to redirect anyone who visits mydomain.com and send them to store.mydomain.com

What is the best way to do this after I install magento?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just configure "store.mycomain.com" as your store URL in System > Config > Web > Base URL.

Then ask your provider to connect both "mydomain.com" and "store.mydomain.com" to your Magento installation path.

Magento will automatically redirect each request to "store.mydomain.com".

Hope it helps.

Comment: this didn't work. I'm not sure i implemented it correctly.
I changed the base URL to store.mydomain.com and it acted like store.mydomain.com was where my magento was installed.
Thats not what i'm looking for.

Comment: my magento is installed on my live site at mydomain.com
but until I finish developing my site, I don't want people visiting mydomain.com...I'd like them to be directed to mydomain.com/TEMP until I finish developing mydomain.com

Comment: Sorry Phil, I think I understood a different scenario. You can achieve this, but it is not a Magento related question, but a webserver configuration matter. If you cannot do that you can also "hack" your index.php file by adding at the very beginning: header('Location: http://example.com/TEMP'); exit;

NOTE: This will not allow you to access the NEW website anymore, so you should create a copy of index.php (let's say: index2.php) and access your NEW website with example.com/index2.php.

I hope I ucorrectly understood your request.

Comment: @Phoenix128_RiccardoT I have cloned my localhost website and rename db name, and change core_config_data, still redirect to old website?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you change the secure and non-secure web address in the core_data of the database.  Then - after you make that change, make sure to clear the var/session folder and the var/cache folder.

This should allow you to run the store as the new URL store.mydomain.com.

If you are actually talking about running magento on the same server and having BOTH run from the public_html folder and then also the public_html/TEMP folder - you'll need to configure the apache to point to a new website located at public_html/TEMP.  This can be done by creating a new website/file in the etc/apache2/sites-available section, and running a2ensite on it with a apache2 restart.

Additionally, you'll need to make a copy of the production database, and then edit the local.xml file in the TEMP install to point to the copy.  Finally, update core_data to update the URLs, clear session and cache folders, and you should be good to go.